# Creating a Unit Test: Private Accessor for TimeClock_Append is not found. Please rebuild the containing project or run the Publicize.exe manually

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, rest, .net-3.5

I am trying to create a unit test on a method that looks like this:

```
Public Function TimeClock_Append(ByVal timeClockUploadJson As TimeClockUploadJson) As TimeClockUploadJson Implements IResourceCommanderData.TimeClock_Append
...
End Function
```

When I right click on the function name and select "Create Unit Test", this is what I get...

```
'TODO: Ensure that the UrlToTest attribute specifies a URL to an ASP.NET page (for example,
' http://.../Default.aspx). This is necessary for the unit test to be executed on the web server,
' whether you are testing a page, web service, or a WCF service.
'''<summary>
'''A test for TimeClock_Append
'''</summary>
<TestMethod(), _
 HostType("ASP.NET"), _
 AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\Projects\ACS.ResourceCommander 3.8\ACS.ResourceCommander.WCFRest", "/ACS.ResourceCommander.WCFRest"), _
 UrlToTest("http://localhost/ACS.ResourceCommander.WCFRest")> _
Public Sub TimeClock_AppendTest()
    'Private Accessor for TimeClock_Append is not found. Please rebuild the containing project or run the Publicize.exe manually.
    Assert.Inconclusive("Private Accessor for TimeClock_Append is not found. Please rebuild the containing" & _
            " project or run the Publicize.exe manually.")
End Sub
```

I don't understand the "Private Accessor for TimeClock_Append is not found. Please rebuild the containing project or run the Publicize.exe manually" message.

I've tried deleting the file in the Test References folder pertaining to this method, and then right clicking on the method and selecting "Create Private Accessor", and that solved nothing.

How can I solve this?